# Invoke or call an app from inside my application in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to invoke an application from my own App and incase that the invoked app is not installed, open the app store?

Does ios7 or 8 allow that kind of functionality?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iphone apps that supports URL schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667920/iphone-apps-that-supports-url-schema)

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom URL scheme in the other app, and call openURL in the calling app.